# How to express the following as a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How you you express $$1+3+6+10+15+21+28+...$$ as a summation? I've tried different ways but they were wrong and always brought me back to square one. Thanks!

Comment: These are the triangular numbers $T_n=n(n+1)/2$. If you want the sum of the first $m$ of them, it's $m(m+1)(m+2)/6.$

Comment: You probably want this summation to stop at some point, if you don't want this to diverge.

Comment: I suppose one can argue that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1$ will work.

Comment: Well I didn't need an actual summation, I just wanted the formula which would give me that sequence, but I didn't know how to word the question most properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the $nth$ term $S(n)$ of your sum, we have $\displaystyle S(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n k = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

*If you want the sum of the first* $n$ such terms, $S(1) + S(2) + ... + S(n)$ use:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2} = \dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$

See the link to [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) to learn more!

Comment: Thanks, I actually got really close to this but I didn't think a quadratic would work.

Comment: You're welcome, Ovi! Sums are fun to work with, and trying to work them out, as you did, helps develop intuition about sums.

Comment: You're missing an $n$ in your first formula.

Comment: Thanks, @Javier I'm having a bad day in terms of typos!

Comment: @amWhy: I have a lot of those days! Nice write up + 1

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$

Why: we want the $i^\textrm{th}$ term to be $1+2+\cdots+i$.

Comment: Thanks, I actually got really close to this but I didn't think a quadratic would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the sequence being summed as a recurrence relation for $n \geq 2$, assuming we index the sequence as $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots)$, as:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+n.$$
Recurrence relations of this form with $a_n=a_{n-1}+p(n)$ for $p(n)$ a polynomial, where the degree of the polynomial is say $m \geq 0$, have $a_n$ of the form:
$$a_n=c_0+c_1n+\cdots +c_mn^m+c_{m+1}n^{m+1}.$$
Therefore, our general term $a_n$ will look like
$$a_n=c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2$$
and we can use the information that $a_1=1,a_2=3$ and $a_3=6$ to get
$$a_1=c_0+c_1+c_2=1$$
$$a_2=c_0+2c_1+4c_2=3$$
$$a_3=c_0+3c_2+9c_2=6.$$
We then solve the above system of linear equations to get that $c_0=0,c_1=\frac{1}{2},$ and $c_2=\frac{1}{2}$ which gives upon simplification that
$$a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=T_n$$
the $n^{th}$ triangular number. Thus finally,
$$1+3+6+10+15+\cdots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Good up until the last part. They're not interested in infinite series.

Answer (score 0):

$$S_n=1+3+6+10+15+\cdots+T_n$$

$$S_n=1+3+6+10+15+\cdots+T_{n-1}+T_n$$

On subtraction, $$0=1+(3-1)+(6-3)+(10-6)+(15-10)+\cdots+(T_n-T_{n-1})-T_n$$

$$\implies T_n=1+2+3+\cdots\text{up to }n\text{ terms}=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

$$\text{Now, }(r+1)^3-r^3= 6\frac{r(r+1)}2+1$$ (Observe the [Telescoping Sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html) in the Left Hand Side)

Putting $r=1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$ and adding them we get, 
 $$(n+1)^3-1=6S_n+n$$
$$\implies 6S_n=n^3+3n^2+3n+1-1-n=n^3+3n^2+2n=n(n+1)(n+2)$$